# Does AWS SES support using S/MIME to sign and encrypt the email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, smime

Can someone please let me know does AWS SES support using S/MIME to sign and encrypt the email.

Comment: Please note that SES doesn't sign emails for you, you need to either use sendrawemail or SMTP to use your own signature on the client side before you even relay the emails to SES.

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html):

> **End-to-End Encryption** You can use Amazon SES to send messages that are
>   encrypted using S/MIME or PGP. Messages that use these protocols are
>   encrypted by the sender. Their contents can only be viewed by
>   recipients who possess the public keys that are required to decrypt
>   the messages.
>
> Amazon SES supports the following MIME types, which you can use to
>   send S/MIME encrypted email:
>
> - application/pkcs7-mime
> - application/pkcs7-signature
> - application/x-pkcs7-mime
> - application/x-pkcs7-signature
>
> Amazon SES also supports the following MIME types, which you can use
>   to send PGP-encrypted email:
>
> - application/pgp-encrypted
> - application/pgp-keys
> - application/pgp-signature